Possessive of time / belonging to the ages: time’s or times’
Given that in the following phrase, "times" is equivalent to all time periods, or ages, from the beginning of time through the end of time, where would the apostrophe be placed: "time’s eternal shore," or "times’ eternal shore"?

With one shore belonging to some noun, seems like a singular noun will do.

Singular or plural, I have no idea what possible meaning the possessive of time(s) could add to a collocation like eternal shore.

...but time's great river (the great river of time) is always possessive singular.

Times is arguably used as a noncount usage (The times they are a-changin': no acceptance of a numeral), but even so the plural-form version requires a definite article.

My thanks to @EdwinAshworth for correcting my use of "partitive."
Part of the problem is that "time" is nondiscrete, similar to the word "water." Yes, we can look at a molecule of water (H2O) or a quantum of time (e.g., one second as measured by humanity), but the word is normally used in an uncountable (nondiscrete) manner. So the question becomes, what's your context?

If you are talking about all of time, then the correct construct is "time's eternal shore." In other words, the phrase "eternal shore" is modifying just one thing: time (all of it, whatever that means).

If you are talking about blocks or periods of time, such as ages, eras, and epochs, then you would use "times' eternal shores." In other words, the phrase "eternal shore" is modifying multiple blocks of time. Please note the conversion of "shore" to "shores."


Now let's look at the stated context:

"times" is equivalent to all time periods, or ages, from the beginning of time through the end of time.

Despite saying you wanted to deal with all blocks of time throughout all of time (keeping in mind that the division of time is merely a label, one block of time cannot stand independent of another block of time as two bricks could), what you're dealing with is multiple blocks or periods of time regardless the quantity. That expects the grammar of my answer #2.
However, all bets are off when it comes to poetry
One last thing: The rules of grammar bend to the needs of poetry. I'm assuming you're working on something poetic because, well... time doesn't have a shore.  If the concept you're trying to express requires a singular to modify a plural, then that's the way it is. For example, if the idea you're trying to convey is that various periods of time (e.g. "ages") all beat against the same shore, then the phrase "times' eternal shore" makes sense.
But without a much larger sample of your text, it's impossible to know if what I just said is true.

The word you want is nondiscrete [Wiktionary] rather than partitive. In 'a slice of bacon', obviously  the bacon  before slicing (the loin, say) is nondiscrete, but in 'some of the biscuits', the biscuits are obviously discrete elements.  Both are partitive noun phrases ('partitives').

(Note, there's also the archaic/poetic usage "waters.")

@AndyBonner I actually wrote about three paragraphs about that... then concluded it was a distraction from the answer. It would have helped knowing more about the OP's actual problem.
